# My database uses TCP port XZY. Why don't I need XZY open on my webserver?

Tags: database, tcp, webserver

I'm given to understand that the port number is actually a series of bits in the packet, so if say I have PostgreSQL listening on 5432 and nginx on 80, why does a packet that exits my database server "via" port 5432 (as per my firewall rules) get picked up by the webserver and forwarded to nginx (who is listening on 80)?

I'm trying to understand why my `iptables` file works with this omission when I didn't think it would.

Comment: Your webapp talks to your database behind the firewall. It doesn't forward database traffic directly to browsers.

Comment: How then does the webserver firewall know that the packet originating from the postgres (exiting the DBServer via port 5432) should be forwarded on to nginx on 80? Doesn't the packet's port "header" have 5432 rather than 80 in it?